# Error Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot find data type dbo.EmpClaveListV2 SQL 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-management

tengo este error al querer ejecutar un SP de otro servidor en el mio pero no se porque sea... EmpClaveListV2 esta es una tabla temporal que esta creada en el otro servidor. Alguien tiene una idea de porque me sale este error? Estoy usando SQL Server 2016

> Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot find data type
> dbo.EmpClaveListV2. Parameter or variable '@EmpData_Dummy' has an
> invalid data type.

Y con estos datos quiero ejecutar el SP,

```
declare  @cur_clave_str varchar(250) = 'MX2020,EU2023'
declare @EmpData_Dummy [dbo].[EmpClaveListV2]
insert into @EmpData_Dummy (emp_clave)
(
       select '1' as emp union all
       select '2' as emp union all
       select '3' as emp union all
       select '4' as emp union all
       select '5' as emp union all
       select '6' as emp union all
       select '7' as emp union all
       select '8' as emp union all
       select '9' as emp union all
       select '10' as emp union all
       select '11' as emp union all
       select '12' as emp union all
       select '13' as emp union all
       select '14' as emp union all
       select '15' as emp union all
       select '16' as emp union all
       select '17' as emp union all
       select '18' as emp union all
       select '19' as emp union all
       select '20' as emp union all
       select '21' as emp union all
       select '22' as emp union all
       select '23' as emp union all
       select '24' as emp union all
       select '25' as emp
);

--/ Reporte  
exec [DBSourceServer].[SourceDWHTemp].[dbo].[dbo.Report_201873]
             @DateStart ='2023-03-01',
             @DateEnd= '2023-04-14', 
             @cur_clave_str = @cur_clave_str,
             @EmpData = @EmpData_Dummy
```

Comment: EmpClaveListV2 es un dataType en el otro servidor debes de crearlo en tu servidor

Comment: @JorgeLuis ya cree en mi servidor el TABLE TYPE EmpClaveListV2 que necesitaba que estoy asignando a la variable EmpData_Dummy , pero ahora tengo este error " Table-valued parameters are not allowed in remote calls between servers. "

Comment: No se puede pasar tablas por sp si el sp esta en otro server

Comment: @JorgeLuis por eso mismo creé una tabla igual con el mismo schema y me salio el error que te comente y al investigar es porque al parecer los parámetros con valores de tabla NO se admiten en todos los servidores, sabrias alguna manera de reemplazar esto por algoque pueda funcionar en el servidor remoto? acepto cualquier consejo porfavor :)

Answer (score 0):

hOLA EmpClaveListV2 es un dataType en el otro servidor debes de crearlo en tu BD.

o ver en el otro servidor que tipo de dato es y sustituirlo en tu sp, POR EJEMPLO SI DICE QUE ES VARCHAR(50) tu lo puedes poner asi

> `declare @EmpData_Dummy VARCHAR(50)`